# TypeScript: Is it possible to create an empty object from generic type?

Tags: typescript, web

Let's say I have a generic type T and I want to initialize an empty object of type T. I imagine something like this but I can't get it to work.

```
type Phone = {
 number: string;
 isMain: boolean;
}

const newPhone = createEmptyObj<Phone>();

console.log(newPhone);
/*
{
  number: '';
  isMain: false;
}
*/
```

Comment: Not possible. After transpilation, no type information remains. So there is nothing from which the javascript runtime can deduce what needs to be constructed.

Comment: Having a type parameter that is not associated with the type of any parameter is almost always an indication that you need to rethink things

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible. Because it's a `type` you have to define everything manually, the same applies to an `interface`.

If you want to have default values you need to use a `class` with defined default values.

```js
class Phone {
 number: string = '';
 isMain: boolean = false;
}

const newPhone = new Phone();

console.log(newPhone);
/*
{
  number: '';
  isMain: false;
}
*/
```

Comment: A class isn't needed for default values, you can have an object or an object factory.

Comment: Object has own values. Not default values. Default values are present only in class prototype.

Comment: You can create inherit directly from any object, also you could a factory function

Comment: You can generate a json file and parse it as binary too or to do a lot of strange things in JavaScript. Nobody says it’s good or bad. I would like to see how much more code we need to write in case of a factory function or inherit any object instead of using tool that was made for initialization. You are always welcome to post an answer.